# Can I extend a generic type in Python?

Tags: python

This is what I want to do:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic  

T = TypeVar('T')

class Parent:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Parent's constructor called")
        self.value = 2

    def get(self):
        return self.value

class Child(T):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Child's constructor called")
        super().__init__()


ch = Child[Parent]()
print(ch.get())
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/inherit.py", line 13, in 
    class Child(T):
  File "/home/.../.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.__constraints__ = tuple(_type_check(t, msg) for t in constraints)
  File "/home/.../.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 640, in 
    self.__constraints__ = tuple(_type_check(t, msg) for t in constraints)
  File "/home/.../.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 166, in _type_check
    raise TypeError(f"{msg} Got {arg!r:.100}.")
TypeError: TypeVar(name, constraint, ...): constraints must be types. Got (~T,).
```

Apparently, this is the right way of writing that code:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic  

T = TypeVar('T')

class Parent:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Parent's constructor called")
        self.value = 2

    def get(self):
        return self.value

class Child(Generic[T]): # <-- "Generic" was added here
    def __init__(self):
        print("Child's constructor called")
        super().__init__()


ch = Child[Parent]()
print(ch.get())
```

But this one also errors out:

```
Child's constructor called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/inherit.py", line 20, in 
    print(ch.get())
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Which is totally expected. Now my question is whether it is possible to extend a generic type in Python at all or not? If it is, how?

Comment: Add the parts in previous comments to the question.

Comment: If you want to create new classes on the fly, use `type`? `ch = type('Child', (GenericParent, OtherParent), {})()`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has multiple inheritance for this purpose.

```py
class Child(Parent, Generic[T]):
```

The `Generic` is only a type-hint, it doesn't affect the interpreter behaviour, you still have to inherit Parent.

Edit: there's also composition

```py
class Child(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, parent: T):
        print("Child's constructor called")
        self.parent: T = parent

    def get(self):
        return self.parent.get()

ch = Child[Parent](Parent())
print(ch.get())
```

Edit2: you can override the `__getattr__` method to enable child to reuse parent functions in composition, but you cannot type-hint this easily, and it won't be pythonic.

```py
class Child(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, parent: T):
        print("Child's constructor called")
        self.parent: T = parent

    def __getattr__(self, item: str):
        try:
            return super().__getattr__(item)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.parent, item)

ch = Child[Parent](Parent())
print(ch.get())
```

Edit3: as mentioned by @deceze you can also create new classes on the fly using `type` but the type-hints will need some work.

```
ch = type('Child', (ChildClass, ParentClass), {})()
```

usage [as docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Parent:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Parent's constructor called")
        self.value = 2

    def get(self):
        print("Parent's get called")
        return self.value

class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Child's constructor called")
        super().__init__()

    def set(self, v):
        print("Child's set called: ", v)
        self.value = v

ch = type('Child', (Child, Parent), {})()
print(ch.get())
ch.set(3)
print(ch.get())
```

which outputs (as expected):

```
Child's constructor called
Parent's constructor called
Parent's get called
2
Child's set called:  3
Parent's get called
3
```

Comment: You are missing the point. I want to specify the class to be extended at the time of instantiation. Not the time of class definition.

Comment: @Mehran You can do composition, i added it in the answer.

Comment: @Mehran i think you need to define your intended behaviour more clearly.

Comment: My bad. My last statement was incorrect. The `Child` class knows of the `Parent` class. But composition is not an elegant option. I mean if I want to go with composition, then I have to reimplement all the parent's methods. The whole idea of generic programming is to prevent rewriting the code

Comment: @Mehran i think the answer to this will involve overriding `__getattr__` to trick the interpreter and linter, but i'll get back to it when i can.

Comment: I don't see how the last approach is helping ('type()'). You can define a new class for sure but that class is empty. It cannot have its own new methods. Only properties. I tried adding methods, but it didn't work. Please let me know if I can define a new type while adding methods to it. Thanks.

Comment: @Mehran i added its usage, but it doesn't handle type-hints well.